# Adding pyproject.toml to project makes pip install fail

Tags: python, pip, pyproject.toml

I am using `pyproject.toml` to configure `black`. However, when this file is added, `pip3 install -e . --user` fails with the following error:

```
    ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/home/sean/git/auto-md/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps --user --prefix=:
    ERROR: usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: option --user not recognized
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/home/sean/git/auto-md/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /home/sean/git/auto-md/
```

Why is this error occuring and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the discussion in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6375), to resolve this issue, you need to run `pip3 install -e . --user --no-use-pep517`.

The reasons for this are complicated, but essentially:

1. By using `pyproject.toml`, you're indicating to `pip` that you should use the new `pep517` installation process.
2. `pep517` does not support `-e` or `--user`, so it fails.
3. There is no other way to automatically configure `black`, so you're stuck with `pyproject.toml` and `--no-use-pep517`.